# jQuery autocomplete renderItem: remove need to wrap custom html in an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using the _renderItem functionality of jQuery autocomplete to override the default display of the results.

Is there a way to NOT REQUIRE the need to wrap the custom html in an anchor tag? Reason I ask is my actual custom html has anchors within it and to wrap the entire custom html in an anchor itself is making it look naff.

Surely this must be possible?!

When I do not wrap it in an anchor tag, FireBug is returning an error:

```
TypeError: d.item is undefined
```

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js
Line 5

Here is my autocomplete... you'll see there is no a tag on the "append" function

```
jQuery("#omni-search-input").autocomplete({

                                source: "/json-search/",
                                minLength: 3
                            })
                            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item)
                            {

                                return jQuery("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete",item).append("<div class=''>custom html with anchors in and tables and things<div>").appendTo(ul);
                            }
```